# Converting byte as a string into actual byte type

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, huffman-code

I am creating a compression project in python using Huffman encoding and decoding algorithm. I have to create a file much smaller in size. I am using the byte value that I get from the Huffman tree and writing them into the file as a string literal like '0100101' I want to convert this same digits so that it stores as a binary numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below for an example how to write a list of strings representing binary values stored in one file to another file as bytes. Notice that both variants (the used and the outcommented one) give you the same result.

```
# lstStrBin = ['01001010','10100101','01001011']
lstStrBin = open("binaryToByteString_Cg.txt").readlines()
# byteArr = bytearray([int(strBin, 2) for strBin in lstStrBin])
bytesString = bytes([int(strBin, 2) for strBin in lstStrBin])
# print(byteArr) gives: bytearray(b'J\xa5K')
with open('binaryToByteString_Cg.bin', "wb") as f:
    # f.write(byteArr)
    f.write(bytesString)
```

The content of `binaryToBytes.bin` (which is 3 bytes long and shown in SciTE) is:

[image]
That's it, right?

P.S. Here the content of the binariesFile.txt :

```
01001010
10100101
01001011
```

---

---

`ADDENDUM (2017-04-25)`:

Following a request of OP (see comments) I provide below a two part code for both ways of conversion. The code reads a `.txt` file with `01010101` like lines, writes a binary file `.bin-fromTxt` with a single byte for each line in the `.txt` file and then reads the `.bin-fromTxt` file with the single bytes and writes a `.txt-fromBin` file containing `01010101` like lines. 
At the end of the procedure the `.txt-fromBin` file will have the same content as the `.txt` file showing that the forth and back conversion was successful.

```
with open('binaryToByteString_Cg.txt') as f_txt:
    bytesString = bytes([int(strBin, 2) for strBin in f_txt.readlines()])
    with open('binaryToByteString_Cg.bin-fromTxt', "wb") as f_bin: 
        f_bin.write(bytesString)

with open('binaryToByteString_Cg.bin-fromTxt', "rb") as f_bin:
    bytesString = f_bin.read()
    with open('binaryToByteString_Cg.txt-fromBin', "w") as f_txt: 
        for byte in bytesString:
            f_txt.write( "{0:{fill}8b}\n".format(byte, fill='0'))
```

In case the `binaryToByteString_Cg.txt` file contains:

```
01010101
10101010
00001111
```

the `binaryToByteString_Cg.bin-fromTxt` file contains:

[image]

and the final `binaryToByteString_Cg.txt-fromBin` again:

```
01010101
10101010
00001111
```

Comment: since my file contains way more elements, and it is throwing me error saying : ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)

Comment: How will I change it back to string?? @Claudio

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'binary number' you mean integer:

```
>>> int('0100101', 2)
37
```

Simply convert your string to an integer using the built-in `int` function with `2` as a base.

Comment: That is not what I was looking for. what I meant is that, I have a string, for example ' 0100101' and I want to store it as a bit code in a binary file. I wanted help with convertion